# handle screen rotation with 3 fragments, every one with 3 different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

I stuck in a little bit problem. 
I have situation like this:
Login activity with one layout.
Three Fragment every one with three different layouts, (Phone portrait, landscape, Tablet landscape)
For better image, Fragments function is: login, register and confirmation code.
What i want to achieve is, good screen rotate + after rotate open correct fragment with stored register data.
I'm not sure if it will helpful but i use in project greenrobot event bus.
What i need is suggestion how i could implement it correctly. Which is best approach etc.
Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Can you show us an overview of what your app look like ? What is included in each fragment layout ?

Comment: yes, but how would you like to get it? You want a txt description?

Comment: Post xml files or describes nodes like "an ImageView and a TextView in a vertical oriented Linear Layout".

Comment: Hmm basically i every layout is in separate file. I think orientation and content is no important here because i don't wan't to add content dynamically. I wan't to only load good layouts when screen change in example onConfigurationChanged and load data back to fields. I suppose in onSavedInstanceState will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You should use quantifiers to load the great layout depending on your screen size and orientation.

For example, *activity_main.xml* from **layout-large-land** and **layout** folders wont react the same. The first one will only be loaded if you are on a tablet and landscape oriented. The second one will be the default layout.

You will need to use small, large, landscape (land) and  portrait (default) quantifiers.

About loading datas, you can use saveInstanceState bundle. Note that views with an id will automatically handle it.